# I can't find the reason of the IllegalStateException error in my Android app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-console, illegalstateexception

I would like to ask a question about an issue that I have been dealing with for a long time. I have solved many problems in my android application in the store, but I still get the error below from the developer console. I tried to come up with some solutions but it didn't work. I need different ideas. What exactly do I need to focus on and where? Many thanks in advance to those who will help.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod (View.java:6726)
  at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (View.java:6683)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:8160)
  at android.view.View.performClickInternal (View.java:8137)
  at android.view.View.access$3700 (View.java:888)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:30242)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:247)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8656)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: Well, it's something to do with a view's `onClick`. Can you share what XML / Java you have  for configuring `onClick`s? You should also be able to identify where in the app this is happening based on the other threads / logs on the stack traces.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Jake Lee. I never get such an error while working on or testing the application. I have dozens of java and xml files in my project. It has hundreds of onclick methods. Only 1% of daily sessions have this error and I get this output from the developer console. I can't find any other trace. I don't know which java/xml code is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing any of your code, it's impossible to confirm, but I suspect this is due to you having an `onClick` function incorrectly defined in one of your source files that is referenced by an `android:onClick` attribute in one of your XML layouts.

For [reference](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#HandlingEvents), each `onClick` method needs to be public, have a void return type and a single `View` parameter.

EDIT:

Some low-level analysis from Android source code: `resolveMethod` seen at the top of the stack trace comes from [AppCompatViewInflater](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:appcompat/appcompat/src/main/java/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatViewInflater.java;l=422?q=DeclaredOnClickListener)

That method is called in `onClick`, and as you can see the `IllegalStateException` thrown at the end of it clearly explains the problem:

```
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find method " + mMethodName
                    + "(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick "
                    + "attribute defined on view " + mHostView.getClass() + idText);
```

Comment: You're right, but my biggest problem is, as I said before, I can't understand where the error comes from. How many of the dozens of xml and java codes I can share. Previously I removed all onClick calls inside all xml files. I did all the button operations locally, but I still keep getting the same error.

Comment: How do you know that error is from your app? Your best be might be to run your app in the debugger and cover as many use cases as possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, but due to my inexperience, I may not be able to fully understand your question. I am getting this error in developer console. Did you mean this might be devices related rather than app related?

Comment: What do you mean you are getting this error in the "developer console?" Do you mean `logcat`? There's no indication in the stack trace that this error is originating from your app. So it could be another app that is causing the exception.

Comment: I am getting this error in the Crashes and ANRs section of my app's page on google play console. Only very few users encounter this error and this is the only stack trace it gives me. There is nothing important in the logcat logs to guide me. I have not come across such an issue in dozens of tests and conditions that I have already done.

Comment: I added an edit to my answer explaining how the exception almost certainly is due to a missing or incorrect `android:onClick` function. So, if you're **absolutely** sure this exception is caused by your app, I suggest you go over everything again to make sure you removed or fixed all instances of onClick functions.